# Poetry No File/Folder for Package

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a simple project layout

```
myproject on  main [$!?] is  v1.0.0 via  v18.14.0 via  v3.10.9 
❯ tree -L 1
.
├── build
├── deploy
├── Dockerfile
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── scripts.py
└── src
```

The `pyproject.toml` is:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "myproject"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = [""]

[tool.poetry.scripts]
test = "scripts:test"
```

The scripts.py is:

```
import subprocess

def test():
    """
    Run all unittests.
    
    """
    subprocess.run(
        ['python', '-u', '-m', 'pytest']
    )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

When I run `poetry run test`:

`myproject on  main [$!?] is  v1.0.0 via  v18.14.0 via  v3.10.9`

```
No file/folder found for package myproject
```

Comment: Is `scripts.py` supposed to be installed (be part of the distribution packages sdist and wheel)? Because, if not, I believe that `[tool.poetry.scripts]` can not be used to reference something that is not meant to be installed.

Comment: I did not know that. So there is no equivalent "npm run" in poetry?

Comment: Yes, but with plugins, as far as I know. [*`poethepoet`*](https://pypi.org/project/poethepoet/) was the first one (before Poetry plugins were an actual thing), but maybe there are others now. And obviously it can be done without Poetry plugins, with tools like [invoke](https://pypi.org/project/invoke/), [thx](https://pypi.org/project/thx/), [taskipy](https://pypi.org/project/taskipy/), [doit](https://pypi.org/project/doit/), and probably others. I just use Makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

The directory where your `pyproject.toml` file sits needs to be share the same name, e.g., if the name config in `pyproject.toml` is `name = "myproject"`, the directory needs to be also named `myproject`. Therefore, you must either:

1. Rename the directory to match your name configuration in the `pyproject.toml` or
2. Move the `pyproject.toml` file to the correct directory or
3. If you *don't* care about making your project *packageable* by Poetry and only use poetry as your package manager for this project, add `package-mode = false` to your `pyproject.toml`.

**Explanation:**

There's a thread on the official GitHub for Poetry that discusses this issue. The gist of the issue is that whatever you choose for your project name, i.e., `name = "myproject"`, needs to be the direct parent directory of where your pyproject.toml file lives. When there is a mismatch, you get the error you are getting.

Sources:

- [Breakdown of the cause of the issue on thread on GitHub](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8662#issuecomment-1889657772)
- [A Poetry contributor's response on thread on GitHub](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/8662#issuecomment-1890342329)